Mainnet v1.18.15 - Error with method:getSignatureStatuses
Problem
Hi, I have recently upgraded my mainnet node to v1.18.15 and I am facing below issue with method:getSignatureStatuses .
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>502 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>

I am not facing this issue on v1.17.31.
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "context": {
      "apiVersion": "1.17.31",
      "slot": 271361672
    },
    "value": [
      null,
      {
        "confirmationStatus": "finalized",
        "confirmations": null,
        "err": null,
        "slot": 271356056,
        "status": {
          "Ok": null
        }
      },

Can someone please help me on this?
